# Перенаправление вывода консоли в файл

Tags: c++

Как перенаправить вывод cmd в файл

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AtlBase.h"
#include "AtlConv.h"

void windows_system(const char* cmd);

int main()
{
    windows_system("ping 192.168.0.1 > C:\\Windows\\Temp\\sys.log");

}

void windows_system(const char* cmd) 
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION p_info;
    STARTUPINFO s_info;
    DWORD ReturnValue;
    CA2T programpath(cmd);

    memset(&s_info, 0, sizeof(s_info));
    memset(&p_info, 0, sizeof(p_info));
    s_info.cb = sizeof(s_info);

    if (CreateProcess(programpath, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &s_info, &p_info)) {
        WaitForSingleObject(p_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeProcess(p_info.hProcess, &ReturnValue);
        CloseHandle(p_info.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(p_info.hThread);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Создайте ваш файл при помощи `CreateFile`. В результате вы получите хэндл этого файла.
- При создании файла надо будет указать ему `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`, в которых поле `bInheritHandle` должно быть выставлено в `TRUE`.

  Альтернативно, можно создать файл с нулевыми `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`, а потом применить к его хэндлу

  ```
  SetHandleInformation(хэндл, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT)
  ```
- В простейшем случае (просто сохранить результат в файл) ненулевые атрибуты `FILE_SHARE_...` в аргументах `CreateFile` не нужны. В более сложных случаях, возможно, они понадобятся.
- Поместите хэндл этого файла в поле `s_info.hStdOutput` (и, наверное, `s_info.hStdError`) перед вызовом `CreateProcess`.

  В поле `s_info.hStdInput` поместите значение `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)`.

  Выставьте флаг `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` в `s_info.dwFlags`.
- Через параметр `bInheritHandles` функции `CreateProcess` передавайте аргумент `TRUE`.
- Также, если вы собираетесь передавать единую командную строку с именем выполнимого файла и аргументами в `CreateProcess`, то делать это нужно через *второй* параметр `CreateProcess`.

Примерный код для "узких" строк

```
HANDLE h_file = CreateFile("ping.log", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
SetHandleInformation(h_file, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);

PROCESS_INFORMATION p_info = {};

STARTUPINFO s_info = { sizeof(s_info) };
s_info.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
s_info.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
s_info.hStdError = h_file;
s_info.hStdOutput = h_file;

char programpath[256] = "ping 192.168.0.1";
if (CreateProcess(NULL, programpath, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &s_info, &p_info)) 
{
  WaitForSingleObject(p_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
  CloseHandle(p_info.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(p_info.hThread);
}

CloseHandle(h_file);
```

Этот код прекрасно работает, а "примерный" он только в том смысле, что вам нужно будет адаптировать его к своему окружению.

Comment: А можете сурс добавить, а то так не до конца понятно, буду очень благодарен